# Is it possible to set the value of a file input to files from another file input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I suspect I am going to disappointed on this one, but I would like to know if there is any way to set the value of a file input with files obtained from a different file input.

My example would be a file input which allows multiple selection:

- the user selects some files
- another file input is added (using javascript - this is irrelevant - it could already exist in the original form)
- the value of the second input is set to that of one of the files from the first input
- when the form is submitted (normally, not using ajax), the server receives the files from both inputs.

I realise that people will probably comment on the security aspect, but I am talking only about files that have already been specifically selected by the user (in the first input).
I don't need to read the files (I know I can do that using the FileReader API), and I don't want to submit the form using AJAX - I simply want to split multiple selected files from one multiple file input into single file inputs.

Comment: "I realise that people will probably comment on the security aspect but I am talking only about files that have already been specifically selected by the user (in the first input)" -- The browser doesn't know that, if it allowed you to set the value of a file input, it would be vulnerable.

Comment: I'm not completely clear as to whether the browser knows that or not - presumably the file object which you can extract from the file list is a special object that you cannot change, so to my mind you would simply be passing round a protected object from one place to another. Unless of course I am ignoring the storage realities and the value of a file input is the path to the file in the local file system - certainly the submitted value is just data!

Comment: Rupert, think of 3rd party scripts, like ads, intercepting and hijacking all your file uploads...

Comment: I don't see how that makes any sense - if any third party scripts (which you are responsible for allowing on your page) want to access the files, then they already can by just querying for any file inputs and grabbing the files object from them.

Comment: Okay, I'm probably wrong on my attempts to explain *why* you can't do that, but the fact is you can't set the value of a file input programmatically, and that's for security reasons, whatever they might be. I'm not sure what kind of problem you're trying to solve here. If it's an UI thing, you can get the `FileList` from your multiple file input, and display each file individually as an HTML list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On getting, it must return the string `"C:\fakepath\"` followed by the
>   name of the first file in the list of selected files, if any, or the
>   empty string if the list is empty. On setting, if the new value is the
>   empty string, it must empty the list of selected files; otherwise, it
>   must throw an InvalidStateError exception.

See the [value attribute specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value). So you cannot get the real value, nor can set a new value other then an empty string.

Comment: This seems to be the answer I feared! ;)